# After last windows 10 update httpd.exe can't start

Tags: windows, windows-10, apache-http-server, httpd

On Monday I updated windows 10, and then, on Tuesday I tried to start Apache from xampp, but it failed.

xampp told me to see Windows Event Viewer `Windows-> application`

```
Bad application name: httpd.exe, version: 2.4.39.0, timestamp: 0x5cee4f90
Failed module name: ADVAPI32.dll, version: 10.0.18362.329, timestamp: 0x0ba7a4cd
Exception Code: 0xc0000005
Error Offset: 0x000000000004bc09
Process ID: 0x1a44
Application Launch Time: 0x01d56469430e900c
Bad application path: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Failed module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
Report ID: 09f56fcb-f159-4392-a9fa-b8bd77208e2a
Full name of the failed package:
Bad application related code:
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty generic error. You could try rolling back the update or reinstalling/updating XAMPP ([a new version was released on September 3rd 2019 with the latest build of Apache 2.4.41](https://www.apachefriends.org/blog/new_xampp_20190903.html)).

Comment: I'm getting this exact same error, using plain old Apache in Windows, no XAMPP.  Any ideas?

Comment: @dmikester1 i just reinstall xampp) also i think that reinstall php sould help, but Im not sure))